# Apache strange behaviour:"get" works, but "post" doesn't

Tags: curl

Ok.

I have a script that was supposed to post data to another web page. I use curl and I can request a page with "get" but not with "post". I wrote a python script that works from CLI. When I try to execute it on the server it works only for other pages on the server but not out of localhost.

Sorry, because it sounds unclear but I am not sure where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check your apache configuration for  directive, may be POST method denied for some reasons

Comment: I think that POST isn't denied.